# Search for keywords to import data from Text File into Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract some data from a text file into Excel.

I have a few machines files to import on excel and I want a button to search and open my text file and import the data based on "search for keywords". The keywords are always the same, only change the value next to each one.

I want to search keywords like: "Machnum", "MachVer", "DataA2Storage", "DataA2Storage", "Parameter 100" and "Parameter 200" for example. And add the correspondent value on excel, adding rows for every file I upload.

Example of my text file:

```
// General Info
[System]

// Machine number
Machnum=138
// Machine Version number
MachVer=V9.6.021
// Machine Software Version number
SoftVer=11.2021
// Machine Data storage - A1
DataA1Storage=C:/Machine/DataA1
// Machine Data storage - A2
DataA2Storage=C:Machine/DataA2

(etc...)

//Machine Parameters Info
[Motor1]

//Parameters - Speed
100;260;1
101;890;1
102;309;1

//Parameters - Break
200;300;1
201;1100;1
202;480;1

(etc...)
```

In Excel it should be something like this:

[image: In Excel it should be something like this image.]

I'm new to programming. I can make the button open the files but I can't find a way to add data on excel based on the keywords search. I search a lot of codes but no one fit my needs.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will need to check each line as you read it from the file, and take appropriate action depending on that "type" of like it is: use regular String methods like `Left()`, `Instr()`, `Like` to figure out where the value from each line should go.  It will be a bit tedious but not super-complex.

Answer (score 0):

This file is to loop through each line text file (if you want to iterate through each single value just replace "Line Input" with "Input"). You have to assign FilePath with your text file directory (in this example the text file is called "FileName" and it is allocated in the same directory of the excel file).

```
Sub ReadText()
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Data As String
    
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\FileName.txt"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, Data
        MsgBox Data
    Loop

    Close #1
    
End Sub
```